# How do I get started with MySQL and Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm aiming to apply the skills to hosting an app on Heroku with Python + SQLAlchemy + Xeround  + Redis/Memcache.

What is the minimal software stack that I need? I'm looking at the following:

1. Python
2. A web application framework, like Flask
3. MySQL
4. MySQLdb <-- do I need this?
5. SQLAlchemy

It's obvious from the question that I do not know anything about SQL yet, that it would be preposterous to look at SQLAlchemy already. That's fine. I'm planning to learn the basics then immediately apply them using a Python API, if "immediately" is possible at all.

#### What I have accomplished so far

For an idea of where I stand:

1. Hosted an app on Google App Engine, using my own custom `Model`s and `Property`s for the  datastore, memcache, task queue.
2. Hosted an app on Heroku, but I haven't used a database with it yet.

#### What I'm aiming for with this question

I want to know the software stack that I need to begin using MySQL. I just want to avoid installing stuff that I don't need.

Comment: Hosting your self, or continuing to use App Engine / Heroku?  What OS will the server be?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand, I'll use Heroku for this. But I'll need to learn how to do it locally as well. I'm on Mac OS X.

Comment: If your are going to use Heroku, you should use Postgresql rather than MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL on Heroku, I suggest https://addons.heroku.com/cleardb